# Getting the percentage of a slider

Tags: c#, wpf, slider

**How do I get the percentage value for a `slider` in c# wpf?** I have tried using the `Value` property, but it doesn't seem to change, no matter where the slider thumb is in the slider.

This is my current attempt:

```
double sliderValue;
sliderValue = slider1.Value;
```

I have looked [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.slider%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), but I am not seeing a "percentage" property, or anything that could yield the percentage.

Sorry for the shortness of this question. I could not find the information I was looking for elsewhere, so I figured posting a question here would yield the best results.

Comment: the `Slider.Value` property is effectively what you're looking for. Where are you placing this code?

Comment: Now that you mention it, I actually am binding to that value in the User Control's data model. However, the percentage should always be out of 100. My slider values go to 160, so I get that value instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Value won't give you a percentage, it gives you the current value of the slider, which is always between the minimum and maximum.

To get a percentage, you would use:

```
double distanceFromMin = (slider1.Value - slider1.Minimum);
double sliderRange =  (slider1.Maximum - slider1.Minimum);
double sliderPercent = 100 * ( distanceFromMin / sliderRange );
```

You also say that its always the same, so I would set some breakpoints and make sure it is being called when you think it is.